# In Django, how to send a post-login message to the user?

Tags: django, unit-testing, authentication, message

I have a Django site in which I show a success message to the user when they've logged in. I do this with a signal like this:

```
def post_login_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    messages.success(request, "Hello There. You're now logged in.")

user_logged_in.connect(post_login_actions, dispatch_uid="user_logged_in")
```

That all works fine on the site. But it throws errors when I run tests to test the login facility. Here's my test:

```
def test_home_loggedin(self):
    c = Client()
    c.login(username='MYEMAIL', password='MYPASSWORD')
    response = c.get('/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

(I realise there's nothing in that example to test whether the user is logged in.) Here's the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/phil/Projects/RIG/projectname/django-projectname/projectname/tagger/tests/viewtests.py", line 34, in test_home_loggedin
    c.login(username='MYEMAIL', password='MYPASSWORD')
  File "/Users/phil/.virtualenvs/django-projectname/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 516, in login
    login(request, user)
  File "/Users/phil/.virtualenvs/django-projectname/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 85, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "/Users/phil/.virtualenvs/django-projectname/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/phil/Projects/RIG/projectname/django-projectname/projectname/tagger/models/userprofile.py", line 234, in post_login_actions
    messages.success(request, "Hello There. You're now logged in.")
  File "/Users/phil/.virtualenvs/django-projectname/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py", line 98, in success
    fail_silently=fail_silently)
  File "/Users/phil/.virtualenvs/django-projectname/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/api.py", line 26, in add_message
    raise MessageFailure('Without the django.contrib.messages '
MessageFailure: Without the django.contrib.messages middleware, messages can only be added to authenticated users.
```

(You may have noticed I'm passing an email address as the username. This is because I'm doing something [along these lines](http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html) to use email addresses instead of usernames. I don't *think* this is part of the problem...)

I'm not sure what the problem is here. If I comment out the `messages.success` call then the test runs fine and the Client has successfully logged in. So why does it complain that the user isn't authenticated?

Comment: Did you create a user record to authenticate against before the test is run? The test database won't have any records for users in it when it's created by the test runner.

Comment: Sorry, yes, there are fixtures which load some users first. With that 'messages' line commented out, I can successfully simulate a login with the tests.

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. And you can confirm that request.user.is_authenticated returns True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In normal circumstances, the `AuthenticationMiddleware` will set the user as an attribute on the request object:

```
request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
```

When you add a message, Django will first check whether that attribute has been set:

```
if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
    return request.user.message_set.create(message=message)
```

But now you're running tests and the `login` method of `Client` creates a request object from scratch *without* the user attribute.

So you've got two options: patching Django or making your signal receiver work in this case by changing it to this:

```
def post_login_actions(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
        setattr(request, 'user', user)
    messages.success(request, "Hello There. You're now logged in.")
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, thanks. That does stop the test failing, although I do now get "DeprecationWarning: The user messaging API is deprecated. Please update your code to use the new messages framework." Why's that?

Comment: That didn't happen to me. Are your settings in line with the [docs on enabling the messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages)?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. Strange. I'm thinking this is probably not the best place for such a message anyway - maybe I should make my own version of django.contrib.auth.views.login() and put it in there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend instead of hacks mentioned by @roam, just add `fail_silently=True` argument to your messages calls - just to those ones that need to be run in the specific place like signals listeners (which you don't want or can move them to a view).

```
messages.info(request, "some message", fail_silently=True)
```

This works as it does not raise MessageFailure exception. The tradeoff of not having this message displayed to user due to some other kind of error is not so big when we consider not having tests for that. And this method is fully supported in django - it is not any kind of hack that your teammate developer would think "WTF"?